# How to check if the string is a valid GUID?

Tags: inno-setup, guid, pascalscript

I need to validate the user input and check if the entered string is a valid GUID. How can I do that? Is there some sort of `IsValidGuid` validation function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call the WinAPI function [`CLSIDFromString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-clsidfromstring) and check (at its failure) if the returned value was not `CO_E_CLASSSTRING` (which stands for an invalid input string). Calling the built-in [`StringToGUID`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.SysUtils.StringToGUID) function is not reliable as it raises exception from which you're not able to get the reason of the failure.

The following function returns `True` if the input string is a valid GUID, `False` otherwise. In case of other (unexpected) failure it raises an exception:

```pascal
const
  S_OK = $00000000;
  CO_E_CLASSSTRING = $800401F3;

type
  LPCLSID = TGUID;
  LPCOLESTR = WideString;

function CLSIDFromString(lpsz: LPCOLESTR; pclsid: LPCLSID): HRESULT;
  external 'CLSIDFromString@ole32.dll stdcall';

function IsValidGuid(const Value: string): Boolean;
var
  GUID: LPCLSID;
  RetVal: HRESULT;
begin
  RetVal := CLSIDFromString(LPCOLESTR(Value), GUID);
  Result := RetVal = S_OK;
  if not Result and (RetVal <> CO_E_CLASSSTRING) then
    OleCheck(RetVal);
end;
```

Comment: thanks TLama, thats the quality i know from you. That was exactly the snippet i was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```pascal
Uses System.SysUtils;

function IsValidGuid(GUID: String): Boolean;
begin
  try
    StringToGUID(GUID);
    Result := True;
  except
    Result := False;
  end;
end;
```

If the `StringToGUID` function is not successful in converting a string to a `TGUID`, it will raise an error. This is how I used it in my project and it works fine.

Another alternative:

```
function IsValidGuid(const GUID: string): Boolean;
var
  G: string;
  L: Integer;
begin
  Result := False;
  L := Length(GUID);
  if not (L in [36, 38])  then
    Exit;
  G := UpperCase(GUID);
  if (L = 38) and (G[1] = '{') and (G[L] = '}') then
    G := Copy(G, 2, L - 2);
  Result := (Length(G) = 36) and (G[09] + G[14] + G[19] + G[24] = '----');
  if Result then
  begin
    G := StringReplace(G, '-', '', [rfReplaceAll]);
    for L := 1 to 32 do
      Result := Result and (G[L] in ['0'..'9', 'A'..'F']);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: The implementation of that function is `OleCheck(CLSIDFromString(PWideChar(WideString(S)), Result));` and as such it's the same as the answer from 2015 (which already mentioned this function and why it's not the most reliable).

Comment: I think uncomplicated and more readable code is always better. That's why I posted that answer.

Comment: ...at the price of also returning `FALSE` for other reasons, unbound to a valid or invalid format.